# Discussion on exchange energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, exchange-interaction

When we ionize hydrogen (no exchange energy in hydrogen) by supplying energy to it, electron use it to break the attraction between the nucleus and itself and comes out of the reach of the nucleus. But In nitrogen valence electron releases two kinds of energies when it enters in 2p orbital -

(I). Electric potential energy

(II). Exchange energy

So when we ionize nitrogen, the electron must gain all the energy that it has released before coming out and it gains electric potential energy by using the supplied energy through breaking the bond between the nucleus and itself but in what form and how it gains exchange energy. This means **when an electron gets exchange energy does it stop exchanging its position or does anything else happens to the electron after getting Back exchange energy?**

Comment: You are thinking of it as if we are individually changing these energies. In reality the extraction of the electron will automatically rearrange the energies involved, so that you dont get to consider exchange energy separately from electric potential energy.